# SQL Server DB metadata

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have a requirement to list out all the tables (and the column) whcih has the value 'xyzeee'.

Is there a query to achieve this?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question see here http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Comment: Sure. If you click http://stackoverflow.com/users/275235/lijo you will see the various questions you have asked. If for any of them you received an answer that solved your problem then revisit that answer and click the tick next to it to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

No, wont ever be. This is not doable in one query. You will have to do a LOT of SQL statements in a stored procedure for that.

Is this some homework?

Or - are your requirements more specific than that? I somehow see no sense in this type of query to begin with. I gladly will help you further, but a little more context would be nice.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. While I executed a query, I got an   error as cannot convert 'xxxeee' as INT. So I need to find out which column caused this error. That is the context of this question

Comment: Well, then why the need to query ALL tables? Dont you have the query that caused the error?